# Problems extracting files from a pdf with PyM

Tags: python, image, pdf, pymupdf

I want to extract and save images as .png, from a pdf file. I use the following Python code and PyMuPDF:

```
import fitz 
import io
from PIL import Image
file = "pdf1.pdf"
pdf_file = fitz.open(file)
for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):
    page = pdf_file[page_index]
    image_list = page.getImageList()

    if image_list:
        print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(image_list)} images in page {page_index}")
    else:
        print("[!] No images found on page", page_index)
    for image_index, img in enumerate(page.getImageList(), start=1):
    
        xref = img[0]
        base_image = pdf_file.extractImage(xref)
        image_bytes = base_image["image"]
        image_ext = base_image["ext"]
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
        image.save(open(f"image{page_index+1}_{image_index}.{image_ext}", "wb"))
```

But I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-5-bb8715bc185b> in <module>()
  10     # get the page itself
  11     page = pdf_file[page_index]
  ---> 12     image_list = page.getImageList()
  13     # printing number of images found in this page
  14     if image_list:

  AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'getImageList'
```

​Is it related to the pdf file structure ( a non-dictionary type)? How could I solve it in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention the PyMuPDF version you used. Your method name `getImageList` had been deprecated for a long time - a new name `page.get_images()` should be have been used. In the most recent version 1.20.x the old name is finally removed.
If you have a lot of old code using those old names you can either use a [utility](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/alias-changer.py) to make a global change, or execute `fitz.restore_aliases()` after `import fitz`.